# max and min of $f(x,y)=\log(1-{x \over 2}-{y \over 4})$ in $D$

Tags: real-analysis

I have $D=\{(x,y) \in R^2: x^2+y^2\le 1\}$. In $D$ there aren't stationary points because gradient isn't null. On the boundary?

Comment: I think this is equivalent to finding max and min for $x/2+y/4$ and yes, it's probably going to be on the boundary

Answer (score 1):

Use Lagrange multiplier

$$F(x,y,k)=k \left(x^2+y^2-1\right)+\log \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{4}+1\right)$$

Set equal to zero all partial derivatives

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 k x-\dfrac{1}{2 \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{4}+1\right)}=0 \\
 2 k y-\dfrac{1}{4 \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{4}+1\right)}=0 \\
 x^2+y^2-1=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Which gives $\left(x=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}},y= -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right);\;\left(x=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}},y= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$

See the max and min on the circumference $x^2+y^2=1$ which is represented as a cylinder in the picture. Max and min are along the intersection between the surface $f(x,y)$ and the cylinder

Hope this helps

$$...$$
[image]